# Will windows in Windows 10 workspaces continue to render when not visible?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to use [this approach](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-multiple-desktops-in-windows-10/) to run applications on each of multiple screens, and perform real-time image recognition on each of those applications. What I'm worried about is how Windows treats these additional displays if they arent currently being viewed - will they essentially be "frozen", and stop rendering? Or will they continue to be treated normally as visible applications?

I realize different applications can behave in different ways internally, but Im asking specifically about the behavior Windows will exhibit by default, regardless of application internal behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound Could you clarify? Im not trying to display different workspaces on different monitors. Im trying to use different workspaces to have additional "virtual screens" Lets say I want to run 24 copies of an application and perform image recognition on each of those applications as they render - I dont need to buy 24 monitors, that would be silly. I need virtual displays, and this seems like it might be a solution.

Comment: @Ramhound by the way Ive seen you around this site for years, thank you for dedicating so much of your time for so long to helping others with their problems at no expense to them :)

Comment: Well you can't have 24 virtual desktops....virtual desktop isn't a display and you can only have one activeat a time